# Moment.js run on server time

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

Ok so I'm using Moment.s js and it works just as it should except I don't know how to make it run on server time. Right now it runs based on local time.
Took me a while to even find the script which displays server time and that's where my journey ends. I tried what made sense to me but no luck.

I have no idea on how to "incorporate" this moment.js code that I got earlier today to be able to run on server time.
As I said, it works as it should, all except I want it to run on server time(hostgator) instead of local time.

```
 <script">

            // use Moment.js to display current date in a div (.displayMoment)
            var inputDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('inputDiv');
            var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementsByClassName('displayMoment');
            for(i=0;i<=inputDiv.length;i++) {
                eDisplayMoment[i].innerHTML =  moment(inputDiv[i].innerHTML, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss").fromNow();
            }
                </script>




 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" async></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="serverDate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.js"/></script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div class="inputDiv">2015-02-17 15:31:00</div>
                        <div class="displayMoment"  style="border: 1px solid red; font-weight: bold;"  ><!-- Displays "4 days ago " --> </div>

             <script type="text/javascript">

        // use Moment.js to display current date in a div (.displayMoment)
        var inputDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('inputDiv');
        var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementsByClassName('displayMoment');
        for(i=0;i<=inputDiv.length;i++) {
            eDisplayMoment[i].innerHTML =  moment(inputDiv[i].innerHTML, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss").fromNow();
        }
            </script>



    <!-- Part which displays server time -->
            <script language="javascript">
      document.getElementById("turret").innerHTML = date;
    </script>       

    </body>
    </html>
```

serverDate.js Code which displays server time, got from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269657/right-way-to-get-web-server-time-and-display-it-on-web-pages)

```
        <script>
        var xmlHttp;
        function srvTime(){
        try {
            //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (err1) {
            //IE
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (err2) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }
                catch (eerr3) {
                    //AJAX not supported, use CPU time.
                    alert("AJAX not supported");
                }
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        xmlHttp.send('');
        return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
        }

        var st = srvTime();
        var date = new Date(st);
        </script>
```

Your time is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Changing this line `eDisplayMoment[i].innerHTML =  moment(inputDiv[i].innerHTML, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss").fromNow();` to this
`eDisplayMoment[i].innerHTML =  moment(inputDiv[i].innerHTML, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss").from(date);` did the trick, all I needed was to change fromNow to from(date)

Cred 2 ArtificialSoldier at [Cred](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/370640-momentjs-to-run-on-servertime/)